# Swift notifications not working

Tags: swift, notifications

I am trying to set scheduled local notifications for a simple swift app. My code so far is:

```
@UIApplicationMain

    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


        var window: UIWindow?
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        //Tell app to ask for user permission
            EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().registerForLocalNotifications()
        return true

        }

        func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler:

            (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            scheduleLocalNotifications()
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
        }
```

But when I get to add s`cheduleLocalNotifications()` to my code,

The error line says :

`Use of unresolved identifier 'scheduleLocalNotifications'`

Comment: "Use of unresolved identifier `scheduleLocalNotifications`" Pretty straightforward. You're calling a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: what do you suggest I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I could be way off but try

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications
```